# How to change output filename in a for loop? ArcPy

Tags: loops, for-loop, arcpy

I am using an ArcPy function (ExtractByAttributes) in a for loop. I have a series of files names  ("i") in a list (test). They are rasters for which I want to run a process in ArcPy.

The for loop basically builds the path to find each raster in the first line and then runs the ArcPy process (Extract by Attributes). As written now, the loop runs correctly but in each iteration it overwrites the result file. How can I rewrite this so the variable "result" has a different name in every iteration?

```
for i in test:
    path = folder_path + "\\" + i + "\\" + i + '.tif'
    result = ExtractByAttributes(path,"VALUE = 10 OR VALUE = 30")
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of the same length and store the results in there.

```
results = [len(test)]
for i in range(len(test)):
    path = folder_path + "\\" + test[i] + "\\" + i + '.tif'
    results[i] = ExtractByAttributes(path,"VALUE = 10 OR VALUE = 30")
```

Comment: Thanks @bbnt! Unfortunately that won't work as each "result" is a raster file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
for i in rasters:
    path = folder_path + "\\" + i + "\\" + i + '.tif'
    print(path)
    result = ExtractByAttributes(path,"VALUE = 10 OR VALUE = 30")
    result.save(folder_path + "\\" + str(i) + ".tif")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).